# Validating the value of several variables

Tags: python

**What I am after:** The user is allowed to input only 0 or 1 (for a total of 4 variables). If the user inputs for example 2, 1, 1, 0 it should throw an error saying `Only 0 and 1 allowed`.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
if (firstBinary != 0 or firstBinary != 1 and secondBinary != 0
      or secondBinary != 1 and thirdBinary != 0 or thirdBinary != 1
      and forthBinary != 0 or forthBinary != 1):
    print('Only 0 and 1 allowed')
else:
    print('binary to base 10: result)
```

**Problem:** When I use such a statement, I get either the result even when I input for example 5, or I get 'only 0 and 1 allowed' even though I wrote all 1 or 0.

---

I found this which seemed to be what I was after, but it is still not working like I want it to:

```
if 0 in {firstBinary, secondBinary, thirdBinary, forthBinary} or 1 in \
    {firstBinary, secondBinary, thirdBinary, forthBinary}:
    print("Your result for binary to Base 10: ", allBinaries)
else:
    print('Only 0 and 1 allowed')
```

This code basically gives me the same result as what I get with the first code sample.

Comment: Are you sure `print("Your result for binary to Base 10: ", allBinaries)` shouldn't be indented ?

Comment: i am sorry, what do you mean by indented (bad english)? the variable allbinaries is just multiplying a, b, c, d with 8, 4, 2, 1 and adding them together. if this is what u ment

Comment: I meant adding spaces before the line so that it is inside the if block

Comment: oh yes! you are right, i am sorry that was a typo. corrected :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = 0, 1, 1, 2

if any(x not in [0, 1] for x in [v1, v2, v3, v4]):
    print "bad"
```

of course, if you use a list it will look even better

```
inputs = [1, 1, 0 , 2]

if any(x not in [0, 1] for x in inputs):
    print "bad"
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and easy to understand!

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the operator precedence in python. The `or` operator is of higher precedence than the `and` operator, the list looks like this:

1. `or`
2. `and`
3. `not`
4. `!=`, `==`

(Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

So, python interprets your expression like this (the brackets are to clarify what is going on):

```
if (firstBinary != 0 or (firstBinary != 1 and secondBinary != 0 or (secondBinary != 1 and \
thirdBinary != 0 or (thirdBinary != 1 and forthBinary != 0 or (forthBinary != 1)))))
```

Which results in a different logic than what you want. There are 2 possible solutions to this, the first one is to add brackets to make the expression unambiguous. This is quite tedious and long-winded:

```
if ((firstBinary != 0 or firstBinary != 1) and (secondBinary != 0 or secondBinary != 1) and \
(thirdBinary != 0 or thirdBinary != 1) and (forthBinary != 0 or forthBinary != 1))
```

The other approach is to use the in-built `all` function:

```
vars = [firstBinary, secondBinary, thirdBinary, fourthBinary]
if not all(0 <= x <= 1 for x in vars):
    print("Only 0 or 1 allowed")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd break it down into the two parts that you're trying to solve:

Is a particular piece of input valid?
 Are all the pieces of input taken together valid?

```
>>> okay = [0,1,1,0]
>>> bad = [0,1,2,3]

>>> def validateBit(b):
...    return b in (0, 1)

>>> def checkInput(vals):
...    return all(validateBit(b) for b in vals)
...
>>> checkInput(okay)
True
>>> checkInput(bad)
False
>>>
```

Comment: In general, I think this answer shows a better style than all of the one-liners, because it separates each operation into orthogonal functions. It certainly is easier to understand what it does in a quick glance. (And was right the first time -- many of the other answers had to be edited to have correct code!)

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [firstBinary, secondBinary, thirdBinary]
if set(values) - set([0, 1]):
    print "Only 0 or 1, please"
```